# When I try to show an image on linklabel click, I get an error

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to show an image on linklabel click, I get an error: unrecognized escape sequence.

Code:

```
public void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
           "mspaint~C:\Users\Joshua Banks\Desktop\Downtown_atlanta_night.jpg");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the \ chararacters in your string (the image path) by either escaping them with another \ or using a verbatim string.

escape characters:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mspaint~C:\\Users\\Joshua Banks\\Desktop\\Downtown_atlanta_night.jpg");
```

verbatim string literal:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"mspaint~C:\Users\Joshua Banks\Desktop\Downtown_atlanta_night.jpg");
```

Comment: so like this:  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("@mspaint~C:\Users\Joshua Banks\Desktop\Downtown_atlanta_night.jpg");

Comment: not quite like that - I've updated my answer to demonstrate what I'm suggesting

Comment: still get an unrecognized escape sequence on on Downtown...when using the first method!

Comment: check that all your slashes are escaped (I just saw that I missed one! - answer updated)

Comment: ok, i get a unhandled exception now, saying they can not find the file, when it is indeed here on the desktop!!

Comment: would it have something to do with what type of file it is?

Comment: Click **Start->Run**, and type the following: `mspaint~C:\Users\Joshua Banks\Desktop\Downtown_atlanta_night.jpg`  Does the file open, or do you get an error?  If you get an error, then no file exists at that path.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that `mspaint~` syntax.  Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: thas wat it was....mspaint was there from a previous way of loading an image...take away mspaint and it works!!!